# Load lists from Entity Framework without make the controller wait

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await

I want to load a set of list at the begining of my Web App, to use them later. These lists are static and are read from the Data Base using Entity Framework as ORM. The idea is to load the list at the begining (on the home page after login) and use them all over de App. But I don't want that the home page was waiting for the list to finish loagind. I have tried several alternatives but no one works (or it goes sync or got errors).

**1. First attempt: Calling ToListAsync() and Await to the ToListAsync (Throw Exception from EF)**

There are two version of the list one async and other sync:

```
private static Task<List<EMPRESA>> ListaEmpresasAsync;
public static List<EMPRESA> ListaEmpresas
```

I have defined a function that generates the lists from the repository on EF

```
public async static Task<List<T>> GenerateAsyncListFromRepository(IGenericRepositoryBlockable<T> repository)
{
    IQueryable<T> queryAsync = repository.GetAllActive();
    return await queryAsync.ToListAsync();
}
```

And other one another function to check the result from the async calls:

```
public static List<T> ForceToLoadAsyncList(Task<List<T>> task)
{
    task.Wait();
    return task.Result;
}
```

The I async load the list:

```
ListaEmpresasAsync = TaskManager<EMPRESA>.GenerateAsynListFromRepository((IEmpresaRepositorio)DIResolver.GetService(typeof(IEmpresaRepositorio)));
```

And when the List is needed I force to load:

```
public static List<EMPRESA> ListaEmpresas
{
    get
    {
        return TaskManager<EMPRESA>.ForceToLoadAsyncList(ListaEmpresasAsync);               
    }
}
```

This initial approach throws the following error:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed

**2. Second: Use ToList() and await to the end of the Task.Run() (Problem with empty enumerables)**

Then I tested to use ToList() instead ToListAsync:

```
return await Task.Run(() => { return queryAsync.ToList(); });
```

I doesn't work either.

**3. Third: Use ToList() and await the GenerationList the Force just return the List (Behaviour similar to sync approach. The controller is waiting for all the lists loading)**

Following this approach I change the signature of the funcion to return list:

```
return queryAsync.ToList();
```

And await on the load process

```
ListaEmpresasAsync = await TaskManager<EMPRESA>.GenerateAsynListFromRepository((IEmpresaRepositorio)DIResolver.GetService(typeof(IEmpresaRepositorio)));
```

But this is working similar to the sync process, that means that on the home page the loading time is really high.

I know that on EF, only one async call is allowed for each context. I just want to put all these loading process on the background even if they run sync, and when the list is needed check for the result of the task.

Any idea?

Just for clarification the solution proposed by Yuval Itzchakov should work when the DbContext is not shared among all the loading lists calls, but In my scenario it throws the error related to more than one async call on Entity Framework.

Comment: Why a negative vote?

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code.
First, you need to know that even when making an async call using `async-await`, the request doesn't complete until the awaited operation returns. This is significant, because if what you need is a *Fire and Forget* style operation, this wont do.

If you do want to execute asynchronously (not fire and forget), do the following:

```
public static List<EMPRESA> ListaEmpresas

public static Task<List<T>> GenerateAsyncListFromRepository(IGenericRepositoryBlockable<T> repository)
{
    return repository.GetAllActive().ToListAsync();
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
ListaEmpresas = await TaskManager<EMPRESA>.GenerateAsyncListFromRepository((IEmpresaRepositorio)DIResolver.GetService(typeof(IEmpresaRepositorio)));
```

Making two lists and using `Task.Wait` is useless, you aren't forcing anything other then your thread waiting on the async method to return, which means it runs synchronously.

If what you want is **Fire and Forget**, note the following:

Using `Task.Run` in ASP.NET is dangerous, as it doesn't register the queued work with the ASP.NET ThreadPool, and is exposed to IIS recycling which may cause your background work to terminate unexpectedly. Instead, if you're using .NET 4.5.2 you can use [`HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.queuebackgroundworkitem(v=vs.110).aspx) which registers the queued task for you. If not, look into Stephan Clearys [`BackgroundTaskManager`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks)

Comment: If I use your approach awaiting the result of ToListAsync() and error is getting from EF , about that only one async call is allowed. And I have two separated list in order to make the initial async call with the async version and when it is really needed I use the sync version.

Comment: Are you making any calls elsewhere to the same `DbContext`?

Comment: All the calls are using the same DbContext

Comment: Well, while you `await` on an operation, the thread is free to do more work. If in the meantime, this thread or any other thread attempt to call the `DbContext`, then an exception will occur. This means that by design, you're doing something wrong. You might be better off running this synchronously if things get confusing.

Comment: That's true, I have no problem on make all the list loading sync. I just need that the Controller was free to make other things not related to the DbContext. That's why I use ToList() and tried to await this call in order to continue doing things.

Comment: Well, if the controller does more work which is unrelated to the DbContext, you shouldn't be getting that exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this parallel tasks with EF, however the intention of Using 1 DBContext in parallel threads will end in tears.
The instance members of DBContext are not thread safe ! [DBContext info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx)

You can use a simple pattern that spans threads

- Thread n+1
- Thread N+2
- ....

And await the result.
Each thread must use its own context.
I use this pattern to search many object types at once for a given search string.
But have have a wait to get the overall result is part of the design.
Not sure if that suits your requirement.

[Parallel tasks demo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you have **non volatile** data sets, you can get IIS to cache results.
I use this approach on a Controller Method with NON volatile content.
See the OutputCache Annotation.

```
       [OutputCache(Duration = int.MaxValue, VaryByParam = "id", Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient)]
```

Comment: I really don't need to load the lists in parallel (And I don't want neither) just release the controller to continue doing things while all the lists are loading their content. At the end I am loading the lists at Global.asax in a sync process, that make the app start slower but the clients don't notice it.

Comment: so where does this asynch process store the answers.

Comment: Maybe the line jump is confused "Global.asax in a **sync** process". Currently there is nothing async in my approach, I am still wondering how to make the main interactive thread do not wait for the list loading.